# Using async WCF service in Xamarin.Forms and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this project:
- WCF service hosted in Console application (basicHttpBinding)
- Separated PCL lib for my contracts
- WPF client
- Xamarin.Forms (portable) - three mobile clients.

In WCF I have async service, which I would like to use in every client. Here is my first problem: PCL doesn't support TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern) - on client side. In PCL I can only do APM (Asynchronous Programming Model) in IAsyncResult Begin/End style. Let me show my code:

Here is my WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculatorService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetSum(int a, int b, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    string EndGetSum(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
}

public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
{
    private Task<string> GetSum(int a, int b)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (a+ b).ToString());
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginGetSum(int a, int b, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(state);
        var task = GetSum(a, b);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
                tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            else if (t.IsCanceled)
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);

            if (callback != null)
                callback(tcs.Task);
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public string EndGetSum(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            return ((Task<string>)asyncResult).Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

and host config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MobileWCF.ServerHost.CalculatorService">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9003/CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="MobileWCF.Contracts.ICalculatorService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In every client (Xamarin.Froms and WPF) I use it, like this:

```
    private void bConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strAddress = "http://localhost:9003/CalculatorService";
        BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(strAddress);
        ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> channel = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>(httpBinding, address);
        var game = channel.CreateChannel(address);
        var num = game.BeginGetSum(4, 1, Callback, game);
    }

    private void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var res = result.AsyncState as ICalculatorService;
        if (res != null)
            Debug.Write(res.EndGetSum(result));
    }
```

**My problem is:** On clients like WPF or WinForms I would like to use it like this:
`await service.GetSum(1, 2);` in `async await` style.

**My question is:** How should I implement my WCF contract and service implementation to be able to use it in Begin/End APM style in Xamarin.Forms client and in async-await TAP style in WPF or WinForms programs?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101023/Frictionless-WCF-Service-Consumption-in-Silverligh

Comment: @Gusman that doens't solve my problem. I want to call async method declared in service as APM (with begin/end) as TAP in async await style

Comment: wcf on pcl's don't support await, or you use the begin/end pattern on you change your project type to be shared.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer to this, it is quite easy actually. If you take a look at `Task.Factory` you will see a helper method named `FromAsync<>()` that does exactly what you want. Your client code in Xamarin Forms would look like this:

```
private async void bConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strAddress = "http://localhost:9003/CalculatorService";
    BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(strAddress);
    ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> channel = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>(httpBinding, address);
    var game = channel.CreateChannel(address);

    string num = 
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync<int, int, string> (
            game.BeginGetSum,
            game.EndGetSum,
            4, 1,
            null);

    Debug.Write(num);
}
```

Note that I changed the signature of your Click handler to `async void` to enable async/await syntax.

The main takeaway is that `FromAsync<>()` gives you a simple way to wrap a pair of APM Begin/End method signatures into an awaitable TPL Task object.

Please give it a shot. And if you've already moved on (this question is a week old now), then at least file it away in the back of your mind for next time.